Compute the singular homology group modulo barycentric subdivision
Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $C(X)$ denote its singular chain complex with boundary operator $\partial$ and $n$-th chain group $C_n$. We know there exists a barycentric subdivision operator $\text{sd}: C_n \to C_n$ that is indeed a chain map, satisfying $\partial \circ \text{sd} = \text{sd} \circ \partial$. This also acts as a natural transformation between functors from the category of topological spaces to the category of chain complexes.
Let $D_n$ be the subgroup of $C_n$ generated by all $\sigma - \text{sd}(\sigma)$. Then $D := (D_n)$ is a sub-chain complex. We consider the quotient chain complex $C/D := (C_n/D_n)$.
Using the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to D_n \xrightarrow{i} C_n \xrightarrow{\pi} C_n/D_n \to 0,
$$
we can derive the long exact sequence in homology
$$
\cdots \to H_n(D) \xrightarrow{i_*} H_n(C) \xrightarrow{\pi_*} H_n(C/D) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(D) \xrightarrow{i_*} H_{n-1}(C) \to \cdots
$$
Now consider the map $\tau: C_n \to D_n$ defined by $\tau(\sigma) = \sigma - \text{sd}(\sigma)$. This map is surjective. According to the proof of the excision theorem (e.g., in Hatcher's book), $i \circ \tau$ is null-homotopic, which implies that $i_* $ is indeed the zero map. Consequently, we have the following exact sequence:
$$
0 \to H_n(C) \xrightarrow{\pi_*} H_n(C/D) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n-1}(D) \to 0.
$$
I would like to explore whether $\pi_* $ can induce an isomorphism between the homology groups $H_n(C)$ and $H_n(C/D)$. However, I asked this MO question two years ago, and the answer was negative. Moreover, this response indicated that $\tau$ is an isomorphism of chain groups $C_n$ and $D_n$ when $n \geq 1$, and $D_0=0$.
Therefore, $\tau_*: H_n(C) \to H_n(D)$ is an isomorphism when $n \geq 2$. $H_0(D)=0$ and $H_1(D)$ is the huge group $C_1 / \partial C_2$.
Two years later, as I revisit algebraic topology, I realize that I still lack a deeper understanding of the quotient chain complex $C/D$ beyond the results mentioned above. One possible approach is to compute the homology groups $H_n(C/D)$ for certain simple spaces $X$.
Specifically, for $X = B^n$, I know that $H_k(C/D) \cong H_{k-1}(D)=0$ when $k> 2$.
For $X = S^n$ ($n>2$), I know that
$$
H_{n+1}(C/D) \cong H_{n}(D) \cong H_n(C) \cong \mathbb Z,
$$
and
$$
H_n(C/D) \cong H_n(C) \cong \mathbb{Z},
$$
while for $2 < k < n$ or $k > n+1$, $H_k(C/D) = 0$.
My Question:
My question is: for $X$ being a finite-dimensional simplicial complex, is there an effective method to compute $H_k(C/D)$, at least for $k>2$? The chain group $C_n/D_n$ is too large for me to calculate effectively, and I lack results analogous to those in singular homology, such as the equivalences with simplicial or cellular homology.
While we can derive short exact sequences concerning $H_k(C/D)$, this does not fully determine its structure, even though the groups $H_k(C)$ and $H_{k-1}(D)$ are readily computable when $k>2$.
I suspect that in homological algebra, one often encounters problems involving the homology of quotient chains, and there may exist standardized algebraic methods for addressing them. Additionally, I would like to provide an intuitive interpretation of $H_k(C/D)$.
As I write this, I think of another potentially interesting question, which I believe can definitely be resolved using homological algebra methods. Given a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0,
$$
if we know the structures of $A$ and $C$, how much information can we obtain about the structure of $B$? The questions this and this inform us under what conditions $B \cong A \oplus C$; this resolves a special case for cyclic groups. I haven’t seen anyone else ask this question on MSE or MO, so I may need to post a new thread about it.
For the Background:
This question has a background. As we initially study algebraic topology, we often ponder how slight modifications to some definitions in homology theory affect the outcomes. It is clear that this inquiry will delve into many intricate details and may be difficult to resolve. However, exploring this issue will undoubtedly deepen our understanding of homology theory, clarifying which constructions are essential and which are merely peripheral.
One typical “modification” involves the equivalence relations imposed on the original chain groups. For instance, in Eilenberg's paper Acyclic Models he proves that singular homology is equivalent to the homology modulo "degenerate simplices" (and similarly, singular homology of simplices and cubes are equivalent).
Another equivalence relation to consider is permutation. Suppose $p$ is a permutation of $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$. We can define
$$p \sigma(x) = \sigma(x_{p(0)}, x_{p(1)}, \ldots, x_{p(n)}).$$
We can study the subgroup $U_n$ of $C_n$ generated by $\sigma - \text{sgn}(p) p \sigma$ and investigate the homology of the quotient chain $C/U$. In Barr's paper Oriented Singular Homology, he employs a seemingly more advanced acyclic model method to show that $C/U$ is equivalent to $C$. (A similar theorem holds in simplicial homology, where Munkres proves in his book Elements of Algebraic Topology that the oriented simplicial homology is equivalent to ordered simplicial homology for a complex $K$.)
As seen in the examples discussed, when imposing various equivalence relations on the original chain groups, such as removing degenerate simplices or considering permutations, we can prove that the resulting chain complexes are naturally equivalent to the original ones. This leads us to wonder why we cannot remove more elements.
However, as noted earlier, when we attempt to "quotient out the subdivision", the resulting homology groups differ from the original ones. Can we provide an intuitive explanation for this phenomenon? This is why I seek to delve deeper into its properties.

Indeed, when I finished writing this entire question, I felt that it was quite cumbersome and lacked practical value. However, the idea of "quotienting out the subdivision" initially sounded fairly reasonable. As I delved deeper into the issue, I encountered difficulties that I couldn't resolve, mainly due to my lack of proficiency in understanding "what tools from homological algebra can actually accomplish“. Nonetheless, this is certainly a question I care about.

This post (https://mathoverflow.net/q/33784/166613) deals with the extra question "how to determine the middle group of the exact sequence".

I dont know whether the following observation has been used in this argument, or whether it is useful. There is a map of topological spaces $\Delta^{n+1}\to \Delta^n$ that sends the last vertex to the barycenter and then it is extened linearly. Precomposing with this map defines an element in $Hom(C_,C_{+1})$, where $C_*$ denotes the singular chain complex. Its boundary is exactly $id-sd$, which explains why $sd$ is chain homotopic to the identity.

[This should probably be a comment, but I needed more space.]
Assuming I'm reading the question correctly, by setting each simplex equal to its subdivisions, I think you're basically doing a singular analog of PL homology as described in Goresky and MacPherson's Intersection Homology Theory (among other places).
You replace each simplex by its subdivison but then each simplex in the subdivision can be subdivided, etc. So I believe your $C_*/D_*$ winds up  being something like $\varinjlim C_*(X)$, where the maps in the direct system are all by $sd$. But homology is preserved by direct limit, so the homology of this limit is just the homology again. In other words, since homology commutes with direct limits, $H_*(\varinjlim C_*)=\varinjlim H_*(C_*)$ but by taking homology you get a system of isomorphisms $sd: H_*(C_*) \to H_*(C_*)$ and so its limit is $H_*(C)$.
That said, this would imply that $H_*(D_*)=0$, which isn't obvious to me from first principles, so this all bears some further checking.
